Has "seen by" been removed from Facebook
Has Facebook recently removed  "seen by" from groups. Our Private group has 102 members and the last post that I could see "seen by was Sept 21, 2024. Prior to this I was always able to see how many people were viewing the posts and if I clicked on "seen by" I could also see the names of members. Can I turn this feature back on?

I'm also not seeing "Seen by X" with a 21 member private group. A 2024-09-14 posting shows it, but not a 2024-10-15 one. I'm thinking some developer's finger slipped and a '>' was typed instead of a '<', since they're right next to each other on the keyboard.

Yes, it is gone unless you have over 250 members in your group.

Sorry but that is the exact opposite to what I have found in my searches. "Over" 250 members it will not show. We have less than half that number - 102 so according to the info I have found it should still be available.
